# ImportError: No module named facebook

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, ubuntu-17.04

I tried to setup my project in Ubuntu 17.04. Then the error logged as **'ImportError: No module named facebook'**

I could not install facebook module, got an error

**Searching for facebook**,
**Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/facebook/**, 
**No local packages or working download links found for facebook**, 
**error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('facebook')**

How can I install facebook module on Ubuntu 17.04 to my python application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-facebook
```

python-facebook is installed in your system.